# Server side clusterer for Google Maps

Tags: python, google-maps, clustering

After doing a lot of research on different types of clustering coordinates (server side) I am still having problems with choosing the best approach for my project.

My requirements:

1. Ability to work with more than 1.000,000 coordinates.
2. Be able to filter coordinates by point of interest.
3. Support map zooming and dragging.
4. Fast
5. I can't use any third party services.

Here is what I found:

1. Region [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) seems to the most suitable algorithm.
2. Geo hashing coordinates + Solr for quick retrieval/filtering of points (might only work with small set of data since the clustering will have to happen on the fly)

I would like to know how to deal with map zooming & dragging while maintaining fast response from the server. How can clusters be cached if the maps is dragged, zoomed? Some clusters can be pre-clustered for large areas (continents) but what if there are 10,000 points within once city?

My software stack is postgresql, python, django.

Answer (score 3):

Source Code for Clustering with Google Maps and Python with Django

http://forum.mapaplace.com/discussion/3/server-side-marker-clustering-python-source-code/

you will need to modify for postgres database as this uses MySQL (+spatial extensions)

Working Example:
http://www.mapaplace.com/Vancouver/BC/

Comment: I found this site before. It's much slower than maptimize for example.

Answer (score 2):

[Maptimize](http://v2.maptimize.com/) could be useful.

Comment: I know about their service. However, I can't use any third party services. I will add it to my requirements to make my question more clear.

Comment: This is nonfree, not open source and SUPER EXPENSIVE.

Comment: ...maybe LESS expensive than some open-source IT consultants !

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

https://github.com/biodiv/anycluster

it uses kmeans and/or grid clustering, and you can easily adjust/rewrite it to your needs.